# How do I correctly allow for multiple tasks to access a database file?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I have a server that accepts multiple client requests as multiple tasks that need to read and write from and to a Microsoft Access .mdb database file. I figured I would have the server queue up operations when they call EnqueueWriteCommand and EnqueueReadCommand as tasks, and then have another separately running task (ExecuteTasks) run the queued tasks. This idea feels insanely convoluted, but I can't seem to find or figure out a better way to do this. Here's my code below.

From my testing, I appear to have a deadlock in ExecuteTasks when I call "await Task.Run(() => task)."

What's causing this deadlock? Is my general idea correct in solving this problem with multiple threads? Is there a better way to do this?

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace appDatabaseConsole

{
/// <summary>
/// Contains all necessary components for initializing and interacting with 
    the database file.
/// </summary>
public static class DBHandler
{
    private static OleDbConnection c;
    private static OleDbDataReader reader;
    private static OleDbCommand command;

    private static List<Task> tasks;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the connection of the OleDbConnection components to the database file.
    /// </summary>d
    public static void InitializeConnection()
    {
        c = new OleDbConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\AppDatabase.mdb"
        };
        command = new OleDbCommand
        {
            Connection = c
        };
        reader = null;

        tasks = new List<Task>();

        // Run the Task executor ask a separate task
        Task.Run(() => ExecuteTasks());
    }

    private async static Task ExecuteTasks()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (tasks.Count > 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("tasks.Count exceeded zero");
                foreach (Task task in tasks)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => task);
                    tasks.Remove(task);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Completed task and removed task.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void EnqueueWriteCommand(string commandText)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start EnqueueWriteCommand");
        Task task = new Task(() => WriteCommand(commandText));
        tasks.Add(task);
        Debug.WriteLine("Finish EnqueueWriteCommand");
    }

    public static List<string>[] EnqueueReadCommand(string commandText, int numberOfColumns)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start EnqueueReadCommand");
        Task<List<string>[]> task = new Task<List<string>[]>(() => ReadCommand(commandText, numberOfColumns));
        tasks.Add(task);

        Debug.WriteLine("Just before finishing EnqueueReadCommand");
        return task.Result;
    }

    private static void WriteCommand(string commandText)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start WriteCommand");
        c.Open();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();
        Debug.WriteLine("Finish WriteCommand");
    }

    private static List<string>[] ReadCommand(string commandText, int numberOfColumns)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start ReadCommand");
        c.Open();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        List<string>[] data = new List<string>[numberOfColumns];
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data[column].Add(reader[column].ToString());
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        c.Close();
        Debug.WriteLine("Finish ReadCommand");
        return data;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Would be better to let the database handle concurrency

Comment: I thought even Access allowed concurrent access but if it doesn't, maybe it's time to review whether it's still the most appropriate database system to be using here?